# Continuity of Singular Value Map

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $1 \leq m \leq n$ be integers and $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a map which given a matrix $X \in R^{m \times n}$ maps to the ordered singular values $\sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_m$ of $X$.

My question is: is the function $\sigma$ is continuous?

An idea of a proof would be to consider $\sigma(X) = \text{roots}(\text{det}(X^ T X - \lambda I))$ and use the fact that the roots of a polynomial depend continuously on the coefficients. Would that be a good way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of proof works perfectly well. Another approach you can consider is using the [Courant-Fischer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) definition of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$.